# ExpressJS Fetching value from nested JSON Object

Tags: json

I am using ExpressJS..When trying to fetch value from the req.body, in the console.log(req.body[ndx])(it prints { " c o..... like this as single character)

```
for (var ndx in req.body){
    console.log(req.body[ndx]);
}
```

My req.body has the below nested JSON Object: How to extract count?
req.body["count"] outputs undefined

```
{"count":1,"totalCount":38,"node":[{"categories":[],"foreignSource":null,"foreignId":null,"label":"172.20.96.20","assetRecord":{"description":null,"operatingSystem":null,"category":"Unspecified","password":null,"id":2655,"username":null,"vmwareManagedEntityType":null,"vmwareManagementServer":null,"numpowersupplies":null,"hdd6":null,"hdd5":null,"hdd4":null,"hdd3":null,"hdd2":null,"hdd1":null,"storagectrl":null,"thresholdCategory":null,"enable":null,"connection":null,"autoenable":null,"cpu":null,"ram":null,"snmpcommunity":null,"rackunitheight":null,"admin":null,"additionalhardware":null,"inputpower":null,"vmwareManagedObjectId":null,"vmwareState":null,"vmwareTopologyInfo":null,"circuitId":null,"assetNumber":null,"rack":null,"slot":null,"region":null,"division":null,"department":null,"building":null,"floor":null,"room":null,"vendorPhone":null,"manufacturer":null,"vendor":null,"modelNumber":null,"supportPhone":null,"maintcontract":null,"maintContractNumber":null,"maintContractExpiration":null,"displayCategory":null,"notifyCategory":null,"pollerCategory":null,"vendorFax":null,"vendorAssetNumber":null,"lastModifiedBy":"","lastModifiedDate":1433277477504,"dateInstalled":null,"lease":null,"leaseExpires":null,"managedObjectInstance":null,"managedObjectType":null,"serialNumber":null,"port":null,"comment":null},"lastCapsdPoll":1433277477793,"createTime":1433277477504,"labelSource":"A","type":"A","id":"10"}]}
```

My Code:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser'); 
var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true });
app.use('/index', function(req, res, next){
        var getReq = http.request(options, function(res) {
        res.setEncoding('utf8');
        res.on('data', function (chunk) {
            jsnArry += chunk; 
         });     
        res.on('end', function (chunk) {         
                req.body = jsnArry;
            for (var ndx in req.body){
                console.log(req.body[ndx]);
            }
            next();
        });
        }).end();
});
app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/*+json' }));   

app.use('/index', urlencodedParser, function(req, res, next){
    res.send(req.body);
     next();
});
```

console.log(JSON.parse(req.body)) o/p below ones

```
{ count: 1,
  totalCount: 38,
  node:
   [ { categories: [],
       foreignSource: null,
       foreignId: null,
       label: '172.20.96.20',
       assetRecord: [Object],
       lastCapsdPoll: 1433277477793,
       createTime: 1433277477504,
       labelSource: 'A',
       type: 'A',
       id: '10' } ] }

var options = {
          host: host,
          method: 'GET',
          headers: {
              'Accept' : 'application/json'
          }
    };

res.json(info["totalCount"]);
res.sendFile(path.join(_dirname, '/html', 'index.html'));
```

//Only shows the res.json value not the html page

Below is my html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="shopStore">
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Simple Angular Testing</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css"></link>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css"></link>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/d3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/product.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>

    <div data-ng-controller="scopeCtrl">
        <div data-ng-repeat="x in newRec"> 
            <p>I am product seller {{x.Name}} in {{x.City}} @ {{x.Country}}</p>
        </div>
        {{newRec[0].Name}}  
    </div>

    <div data-ng-controller="nmsCtrl">
     <p>Data to display</p>
    <!--    <div data-ng-repeat="jsn in jsnData"> 
            <p>I am product seller {{jsn.count}} displayed out of {{jsn.totalCount}}</p>
        </div> -->
    </div>  

    <div data-ng-controller="Store-Controller as store">
      <div data-ng-repeat="product in store.products">
        <div data-ng-hide='product.cantPur'>
            <h6>Product:::{{product.item}}</h6>
            <h6>Dollar Price:::{{product.dollar | currency}}</h6>
            <h6>Description::::{{product.desc}}</h6>
            <h6>{{review.stars}}</h6>
            <button data-ng-show='product.canAdd'>Add to Cart</button>
            <product-panel></product-panel>
        </div>
       </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you output the result of `console.log(typeof res.body);` ?

Comment: @Pierre, It outputs String

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you include [body-parsing middleware](http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.body)? [body-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser) support JSON parsing.

```
var app = require('express')();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

`bodyParser.json` also expect to receive payload in `application/json` content type. Example using jQuery ajax:

```
.ajax({
  url:url,
  type:"POST",
  data:data,
  contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType:"json",
  success: function(){
    ...
  }
})
```

Comment: I am already using body-parsing middleware..This is how my code looks

Comment: My typeof req.body outputs String

Comment: how do you send the payload request? The content type should be `application/json` instead of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. See my edited answer.

Comment: you should use parser before the request handler. Move `app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/*+json' }));` to line 3.

Comment: Moved to line 3, it outputs character by character for console.log(req.body[ndx])

Comment: I notice you use `http.request`? Do you receive the JSON object from '/index' request payload or you request it from another site?

Comment: I recieve the JSON Object from different Rest API

Comment: Updated the question with the REST API Call Option value

Comment: In that case, it has nothing to do with body-parser as it process payload from req. I strongly suggest you use [request/request](https://github.com/request/request) package instead of http.request to call external REST api. It include JSON support as well.

Comment: Able to fetch now count after using the request\request package.. But how will i access the value inside accessRecord as it is an object after json.parse

Comment: @firadus how do I send the Json to html, red.send is not working inside the request/request package

Comment: res.json works alone, but if i need to show the res.json in the index.html page, its not working..Updated my code in the end..Shows only the res.json value not all the html content. I use angularJS/HTML. Both works alone, not able to combine html & json data

Comment: I will create a seperate question if you need..please help.. Need to use both JSON & sendfile together

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to convert the req.body into json using

```
bar myRes= JSON.parse(req.body);
console.log(myRes.count);
```

This should be done for you automatically. How is your bodyParser middleware set uup?

It should be set up as in the next post.

Comment: Nope i tried this before, its not able to indentify parse keyword itself.

Comment: Meaning you are unable to call the parse function itself?

Comment: I tried console.log(JSON.parse(chunk)) which outputs unexpected token at Object.parse

Comment: but JSON.parse(req.body) outputs value, added the o/p in my question. please check

Comment: See the edit to my post above. That doesn't do it for you.

Comment: unexpected identifier at exports.runInThisContext when i tried bar myRes = JSON.parse(req.body)

Comment: What happens when you try JSON.parse(jsnArry);

Comment: I'm little confused. You said console.log(JSON.parse(req.body)) printed out the json  structure properly.